# How to create account by web3 0.20 version?

Tags: web3js

I try to create new account by using web3, i found that I can only do this in 1.0 of web3 but not in 0.20 version? it does not support personal.newAccount

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered somewhere previously, however, I'm not able to find the post somehow. 
The essence of the post was that Web3 0.2x.x **does not support the functionality to do this task** but that there are custom wrapping implementations i.e. ethereumjs-accounts which can be used as a solution to the problem. 
 
 Have a look at https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-account, for further details.